# How can I throw a SubmissionError from a non-Submit function?

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm using [redux-form](https://redux-form.com).  I have an `onSubmit` and a `checkStatus` method which both make an Ajax call to the API back-end.  If the result of the Ajax call is not 200, I want to throw a [SubmissionError](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/submissionerror.md/).

The SubmissionError works fine if I throw it inside of `onSubmit` (it correctly shows me an error message on the form).  But if I throw it inside of `checkStatus`, then I get an error complaining about an handled exception:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SubmissionError {errors: {…}, message: "Submit 
Validation Failed", name: "SubmissionError", stack: "SubmissionError: 
Submit Validation Failed at ...) at <anonymous>"}
```

I did see [this comment](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2269#issuecomment-268304672) that makes is seem like you are only supposed to throw `SubmissionError` from within `onSubmit()`:

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { reduxForm, touch, Form, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import ReduxFormField from './components/ReduxFormField'

export interface FormProps {
    handleSubmit: any;
    error: any;
}

export class MyForm extends React.Component<FormProps, any> {
private _inputVal: any;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.checkStatus = this.checkStatus.bind(this);
}

checkStatus() {
    return fetch("/checkStatus", {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            // checkStatus was successful!
        } else {
            throw new SubmissionError({
                _error: "There was an error."
            });
        }
    });
}

onSubmit(event) {
    return fetch("/submit", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({'key1': 'val1'})
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            // submit was successful!
        } else {
            throw new SubmissionError({
                _error: "There was an error."
            });
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <ReduxFormField 
                        type="text" fieldName="myInputValue"
                        ref={(input) => {
                            this._inputVal = input;
                        }}/>
                </fieldset>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

                <a onClick={() => {
                        this.checkStatus()
                    } 
                }>Check Status
                </a>

            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm'
})(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this action creator should help

[https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-setsubmitfailed-form-string-fields-string-code-](http://setSubmitFailed(form:String,%20...fields:String)%20#%20Flips%20submitFailed%20flag%20true,%20removes%20submitSucceeded%20and%20submitting,%20marks%20all%20the%20fields%20passed%20in%20as%20touched,%20and%20if%20at%20least%20one%20field%20was%20passed%20flips%20anyTouched%20to%20true.)

```
setSubmitFailed(form:String, ...fields:String) #
Flips submitFailed flag true, removes submitSucceeded and submitting, marks all the fields passed in as touched, and if at least one field was passed flips anyTouched to true.
```

---

Another option if to create a formField ( I don't mean a visible field, but just inside redux-form) called 'checkStatus' being true by default. When your check fails, simply dispatch action called `change` onto this field and supply the reduxForm with a validator which fails if field if false